# Not getting cognito Access token after login with amzon cognito domain UI (generated from userpool)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

**I'm not getting the access token from aws cognito user pool after authentication, I'm getting code in web url instead of token.**

The step I have done are following :-

Step 1: Created an User pool and setup all the requirements.

Step 2: Added Identity providers credential in userpool left navigation bar -> Federation -> Identity Providers(Facebook, google plus).

Step 3: Done Attribute mapping(User pool left Navigation bar -> Federation -> Attribute Mapping).

Step 4: Enabled Identity Providers and added callback URI(User pool left Navigation bar App Integration -> App Client Setting -> Enabled Identity Providers)(Allowed OAuth Flows -> Authorization code grant)

Step 5: Created URI domain name (User pool left Navigation bar App Integration -> Domain Name) 
and added this domain in Facebook app as well as in google plus account(https://XXXXXXXXX.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse).

Step 6: Open the hosted domain by aws in browser (https://XXXXXXXXX.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=abcdefghi&redirect_uri=https://abcdefg)

[image]

Step7: Login in into open UI and it redirect to successful login with an code in query parameter, not the access token how can I get the access token now in my application.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Authorization code grant` flow will only vend an authorization code to your application. This code can be exchanged for tokens with the Cognito token endpoint.

If you want tokens vended directly to your app, you should use `Implicit grant` flow instead.

Reference documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html

Comment: I have one more doubt, here I'm using user pool because in my application a user can sign in using facebook gmail and cognito. Suppose I have account on Facebook abc@gmail.com same on gmail and I had registered with same on cognito, I had created a lambda function so that I can control the duplicate email either they are from any sign in process every time only a single entry will be there in user pool regarding abc@gmail.com and this single entry will be for all cognito gmail and facebook.

For that I'm using the domain webview on my application. but my requirement is

Comment: ---different, I'm doing this project on Ionic 3 and webview is not the best option I have to create something native, **can you please tell the whole process step by step** for native application using SDK I'm trying to implement same from long time but I failed, every time I created one user pool and federated pool added the user pool id in Authentication providers then when I sign in using gmail or Facebook there will be a  entry in Identities table either from gmail or from facebook login and one from cognito signup process in user pool. now here is 3 user from abc@gmail.com one from

Comment: Gmail, Facebook and cognito, but I have to map them all with one email ID, **How I have to do this with native application using SDK????** or **how I can use that same userpool but without webview using native design**  Please tell me step by step.

Comment: I've hit a similar issue and posted a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547452/how-to-use-federation-from-a-user-pool-not-from-an-identity-pool. Are either of you able to answer? @SaurabhChauhan

Comment: @mipnw Please have a look at above answer and change the Allowed OAuth Flows to Implicit grant.